# How To Use \ In Python List

Tags: python, list, escaping, sequence

Does anyone know the escape sequence to use a \ in a list.

```
List = ['a','B','c','D','\'] # My python interpreter thinks I want 
                             # a line continuation but I want the 
                             # actual  ASCII character.
```

Comment: That it is in a lists is not at all special. You just want to have the string literal with a single backslash.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with the list, but rather that the `\\` character is special *in the string*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work,

```
  List = ['a','B','c','D','\\']
```

You "escape" the \ with another \ in front. As an aside, "List" is probably not the best choice for a variable name.

Basically any time you want to use the \ as a simple "\" character and not the
special Python character you have to use two of them.

So for instance, this will look for a single backslash in the list and print a single
backslash, even though two are used in the code.

```
for c in List:
    if c == '\\':
       print 'Found \\.'
```

Output:

```
Found \.
```

Comment: not the actual name it was just an example and the double backlash doesn't seem to work it just print this '\\'. I'm going for something that just prints one '\'

Comment: @RandomPhobia It's there .. try this: print List[4] and it will give you the backslash

Comment: @RandomPhobia: No, the double backslash is correct.  The actual string in memory contains only one backslash.  The reason it is printing out two backslashes is because that way you can copy and paste it into a Python script and get the same value (instead of a syntax error).  If you run `print ', '.join(List)`, you'll see that there's only one backslash there.

Comment: @Levon Oh I see i was printing the whole list. Thanks Levon

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
List = ['a','B','c','D','\\']
```

Using the double backslash allows you to escape the character. It's elaborated in the [Python Reference - Lexical Analysis](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) section.

It will give you a single backslash back:

```
>>> print chr(ord(List[-1]))
\
```

Comment: @Levon: That was to belabor the point that it would give a backslash.  But you're absolutely right.